# Hard-surface modeling problem - Bicycle Helmet

Tags: modeling, topology

I have been struggling to model a bicycle helmet. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have started this project a couple of times, each time trying different approach.

[image: Basic mesh]

I tried:

- sculpting,
- to model the surface first then the holes,
- to model holes first then the surface.

I can 'see' how the topology should flow, but fail miserably when trying to create helmet basic shape. Reference photos are not ideal and I have a problem to match the shapes basing only on one picture.

[image: topology sketch]

Here is a reference **[link](https://meteorsport.eu/product-slo-37398-Kids-cycling-helmet-Meteor-KS07-APPER-mint-pink.html)** I have been tasked with. Can't change the reference.

Comment: you should probably begin by drawing all the lines from the top view, then change the view and deform the whole shape, etc

Comment: Yea, I have tried that, but the top view is not exacly from top - more from top/front. I ended up with streched front and squished back.
Im going to try that again, if you say so.

Comment: yes you could do it from the side but it seems like it's not completely from side either

Comment: Tried again with modeling from top with drawing all the lines. It came out too complicated to deform and achieve desired shape. At least for me.

Comment: ok see my answer, it's just a start that may inspire you

Comment: Hi :). If this were a client work, it' might be cheaper to actually buy the helmet and have a perfect reference :))

Comment: Actually it is a test task for a job application.

Answer (score 3):

You could draw the lines from top view (something approximately like that):

[image]

Create another object with the side view as model, then shrinkwrap your first object (*Wrap Method > Project*) to this second object:

[image]

Apply the *Shrinkwrap* modifier:

[image]

Begin to move the vertices to sculpt all the slots, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this when I get home and post my results. In fact I created something very similar, but thought it was to complex too work on.

Comment: maybe there's another solution but your object is rather complicated. The main problem is probably that your pictures are not really perpendicular to the object, but I guess you'll be able to correct that

Comment: Yes, that is the main problem. If I had photos from exactly top, side and front, I would be able to create it after couples of hours. But every time I tried with these references I ended up with model matching only one pic and deleting it.

Comment: Hey, I think I have found the solution.
I put the top view on plane, subdivided it and distorted to match the dimensions of side view, while still keeping the shape. It is not perfect, but much better than previous refs, because I can work from two views at the same time.
Im currently working on it. Will keep you updated.

Comment: ok so maybe answer your own questions with some pictures so that we can follow your steps

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have found the way to match top and side view.
It allowed me to match the position of points on two planes - horizontal and vertical - rather than on one and ending up with distorted model.

Here is what I did:

[image: top view ref]
[image: top and side view ref]

I have put reference image on a plane, subdivided it - first horizontaly when looking from top. I moved the lines to strech image and match most important points like holes ends. Then I started to move verts on the very edge of plane to restore the oval shape of helmet. Picture was still distorted, so I added vertical lines (still looking from top) and moved verts inside till everything was more or less correct.

About the back side. I have found, after an hour or more, [**pictures**](https://meteorsport.eu/product-eng-8320-METEOR-KIDS-BIKE-HELMET-HB6-5-white-flowers.html) of very simillar helmet with back picture. It didn't match my model at all, but gave me the idea how to create the flow of topology.

Here are the results of modeling the top part (which was the problem I tried to solve):

[image: result back][image: result front]

Big thank you to **@moonboots** for encouraging me to try again and look for solution.